# I am trying to webscrape from Zomato, however it returns with an output of "None" and Attribute Error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Whenever i try to extract the data, it returns an output of "None" which I am not sure of is it the code (I followed the rules of using bs4) or is it just the website that's different to scrape?

**My code:**

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://www.zomato.com/jakarta/pondok-indah-restaurants'
req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = req.text

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

listings = soup.find('div', class_='sc-gAmQfK fKxEbD')
rest_name = listings.find('h4', class_='sc-1hp8d8a-0 sc-eTyWNx gKsZcT').text

##Output: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

print(listings)
##returns None
```

Here is the inspected tag of the website which i try to get the h4 class showing the restaurant's name:

[inspected element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Mfa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Classes are generated dynamically and may differ from your inspections via developer tools - So you won't find what you are looking for.

#### How to fix?

It would be a better approach to select your targets via `tag` or `id` if available, cause these are more static than `css classes`.

```
listings = soup.select('a:has(h4)')
```

#### Example

Iterating listings and scrape several infromation:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://www.zomato.com/jakarta/pondok-indah-restaurants'    
req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})    
html = req.text    
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

data = []
for item in soup.select('a:has(h4)'):
    data.append({
        'title':item.h4.text,
        'url':item['href'],
        'etc':'...'
    })
print(data)
```

#### Output

```
[{'title': 'Radio Dalam Diner', 'url': '/jakarta/radio-dalam-diner-pondok-indah/info', 'etc': '...'}, {'title': 'Aneka Bubur 786', 'url': '/jakarta/aneka-bubur-786-pondok-indah/info', 'etc': '...'}, {'title': "McDonald's", 'url': '/jakarta/mcdonalds-pondok-indah/info', 'etc': '...'}, {'title': 'KOPIKOBOY', 'url': '/jakarta/kopikoboy-pondok-indah/info', 'etc': '...'}, {'title': 'Kopitelu', 'url': '/jakarta/kopitelu-pondok-indah/info', 'etc': '...'}, {'title': 'KFC', 'url': '/jakarta/kfc-pondok-indah/info', 'etc': '...'}, {'title': 'HokBen Delivery', 'url': '/jakarta/hokben-delivery-pondok-indah/info', 'etc': '...'}, {'title': 'PHD', 'url': '/jakarta/phd-pondok-indah/info', 'etc': '...'}, {'title': 'Casa De Jose', 'url': '/jakarta/casa-de-jose-pondok-indah/info', 'etc': '...'}]
```

Comment: Problem is solved, thank you very much! however it only returned with 9 listings within the page. Should I use selenium in addition to get more of the listings?

Comment: Yes - If there is no api to get the information from, it would be a good approach to use selenium, to scroll down the page end get all the results.